# Understand Intermittent SSL error from dbGetQuery

Tags: r, ssl, shiny, rjdbc, simba

I can use some help understanding the following intermittent error we get w/ an R/shiny app deployed to rs-connect from RStudioPro.

The calling code (which usually works) is

```
RAW <-
    dbGetQuery(imp_connect, "SELECT * from XXXX.XXXXX")
```

imp_connect is the connection object and correctly formatted. The ocassional error is:

> Warning: Error in .verify.JDBC.result: Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for SELECT * from XXXX.XXXXX ([Simba]ImpalaJDBCDriver ERROR processing query/statement. Error Code: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Connection
> reset, SQL state: HY000, Query: SELECT * f()()rom XXXX.XXXXX.)

Any suggestions or referrals are quite welcome.

Comment: maybe the connection timed out, e.g. due to inactivity?

Comment: Happens on first connection from time to time .  Not always but at last once a day.